# Position an image using variables

Tags: javascript, css, variables, positioning

I want to be able to change the position of an image using variables.

I have the following but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can achieve this, please?

```html
<img id="myImg" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/static/apple-touch/wikipedia.png"/>

<script>
var x = "100px";
var y = "200px";
</script>

<style>
img {
  width: 800px;
  height: 1030px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-:transparent;
  margin-right: 1em;
  object-fit: none;
}
#myImg{
  object-position: x y;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and ***expected output*** using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = "100px";
var y = "200px";

let img = document.querySelector("#myImg");

img.style.objectPosition = `${x} ${y}`
```

```css
img {
  width: 800px;
  height: 1030px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-:transparent;
  margin-right: 1em;
  object-fit: none;
}
#myImg{
  object-position: x y;
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/static/apple-touch/wikipedia.png"/>
```

Comment: Thank you that looks great.

Comment: This is [how to accept answer on stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)